# Avoid output an attribute in case of the missing "matching" entity

Tags: xml, xslt

After XSLT execution i have a picture like (some attributes with empty values)

```
  <Document
            Region="Earth"
            City="Tokio"
            District=""
            Street="" >
  </Document>
```

**My XSLT was**

```
<xsl:template match="Document">
     <Document
            Region="{Region/@attr1}" 
            City="{City/@attr2}"  
            District="{District/@attr3}"  
            Street="{Street/@attr4}"  >
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </Document>
  </xsl:template>
```

All Xpathes are correct. The thing is that, as i suppose, my code is too "direct". Need more flexibilty. Briefly, compliance of the condition: "If there is no value\attribute to catch in source XML then there shouldn't be any corresponding record in the output node". In the sample code  {District/@attr3} and {Street/@attr4} Xpath\Expression may return some values but sometimes are not (there is even no attribute in the source node then). So desired output in case when {District/@attr3} and {Street/@attr4} return\"matching" nothing have to looks like:

**Desired output**

```
  <Document 
            Region="Earth"
            City="Tokio" >
  </Document>
```

How to improve XSLT code (1.0)?

Comment: Please always post a [mcve], including input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to advise without seeing the broader picture. Try something like:

```
<xsl:template match="Document">
    <Document
            Region="{Region/@attr1}" 
            City="{City/@attr2}" >
        <xsl:apply-templates select="District/@attr3 | Street/@attr4"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="District/@attr3">
    <xsl:attribute name="District">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Street/@attr4">
    <xsl:attribute name="Street">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

or perhaps:

```
<xsl:template match="Document">
    <Document
            Region="{Region/@attr1}" 
            City="{City/@attr2}" >
        <xsl:apply-templates select="District/@attr3 | Street/@attr4"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="District/@attr3 | Street/@attr4">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name(..)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Untested, because no test input was provided.

---

Note that this assumes the attributes will either have a value or not be there at all - not that they are empty. If they can be empty, you need to add a predicate, e.g.:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="(District/@attr3 | Street/@attr4)[string()]"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is great, but harder to understand for someone that's not too familiar with XSLT.
I would just add if statements to test if the node exists in the source document.

```
<xsl:template match="Document">
  <xsl:element name="Document"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="Region" select="Region/@attr1"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="City" select="City/@attr2"/>
    <xsl:if test="District/@attr3">
      <xsl:attribute name="District" select="District/@attr3"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="Street/@attr4">
      <xsl:attribute name="Street" select="Street/@attr4"/>
    </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

You could also replace

```
<xsl:element name="Document"/> with <xsl:copy>
```